# pip does not honor PIP_INDEX_URL with sudo

Tags: python, repository, pip

According to the [doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver#configuring-pip-easy-install) I can direct pip to use my private pypi repository instead of the official one:

```
For pip this can be done by setting the environment variable PIP_INDEX_URL in your .bashrc/.profile/.zshrc:
export PIP_INDEX_URL=http://localhost:8080/simple/
```

So I added my private repository(e.g.,  `http://pypi.mycompany.com/simple` ) into `/etc/profile` on my Debian server. However pip still raises error:

```
john@server:~$ sudo pip install ipython
Downloading ...
    Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
    ...
```

Looks like pip ignores the environment variable `PIP_INDEX_URL` I've set. Why?

**Update:**

Following @Ivo's direction, I found my Python didn't see the variable at all:

```
john@server:~$ sudo python -c "import os; print(os.getenv('PIP_INDEX_URL'))"
None
```

Comment: Could you report what `$ sudo python -c "import os; print(os.getenv('PIP_INDEX_URL'))"` gives? If `None`, then it doesn't exist for your command.

Comment: @Ivo Exactly as you said, the command give me a `None`. How did that happen? I've added this hint to my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it. It's simple: `sudo` by default will not use the environment variables for security reasons. To tell `sudo` preserve env variables, `-E` option can be used, e.g.

```
sudo -E pip install ipython
```

Answer (score 4):

Sudo sanitizes the secure environment by reseting most environment variables. By default it resets all variables outside of those in its preserve list.  Sudo has three classes of environment variables: check, reset, preserve.  By default it resets all variables outside of those listed in the preserve list.

Available options:

1. As noted, you can globally pass all environment variables with `-E` also spelled `--preserve-env`.

   This represents a security issue. Passing environment variables may taint or otherwise affect execution within a (secure) environment.  Consider the issues of `$LD_PRELOAD` or `$IFS`.
2. `-E` and `--preserve-env` support an argument list of variables to preserve, in addition to the default variables:

   ```
   sudo --preserve-env=PIP_INDEX_URL pip install python
   ```
3. You can explicitly pass env variables to the ssh command via the shell:

   ```
   sudo -e PIP_INDEX_URL=${PIP_INDEX_URL} pip install ipython
   ```

   ${PIP_INDEX_URL} is expanded by the shell before passing to `sudo`.

   This is a handy shell trick and works with `ssh` and anything else that passing args and environment directly to a subprocess.
4. Modify your sudo configuration in `sudoers` to extend the list of allowed environment variables to pass to the child.  See the `env_keep` option.

   ```
   DEFAULT env_keep+=PIP_INDEX_URL
   ```

   I would argue that this option is the cleanest, especially on a system with multiple users that are expected to use the same pip options.

   The last line of your `sudoers` file may contain an `#includedir` directive.  If so, put your modifications in a file in that directory. e.g. `/etc/sudoers.d/pip_environment` and add keep options for `PIP_INDEX_URL`, `PIP_TRUSTED_HOST`, `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` and any other options needed in your configurations.

references:

- sudoers configuration: [man 5 sudoers](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)
- sudo options: [man 8 sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)
- [Secure Programming for Linux and Unix HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/environment-variables.html)
- pip environment variables are named in a format of `PIP_` followed by an upper case spelling of the full command line flag. see: the [pip config file documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file)
- You can view the check, reset, and reserve lists in the output of running `sudo -V` as root:

  ```
  % sudo sudo -V

  # ...
  Environment variables to check for sanity:
          TZ
          TERM
  # ...
  Environment variables to remove:
          *=()*
  # ...
  Environment variables to preserve:
          MAIL
          HOME
  ```